# How to sort my images by name?

Tags: php, arrays, image, sorting, directory

```
/* function:  returns files from dir */
function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg')) {
    $files = array();
    if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
            if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $files;
}
```

I have images named 01-image.jpg, 02-image.jpg etc but when I echo them out, they are in random order, how do I order them by name?

Comment: you can use sort()

Comment: You should try `glob()` instead of `readdir()`, it sorts by default and gives you the option to directly get the files you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you echo them out use sort() - sort arrays in ascending order or rsort() - sort arrays in descending order

You can read more about sorting array [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp)

```
// function to get img

$order = sort($img);
echo($order)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sort with **SORT_STRING** option

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

```
sort($files, SORT_STRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) read the content of the directory to a variable (array)
2) sort the array as you need using any of those: [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)
3) run your while to print the file names..